# find non-matching lines of two files bash

Tags: bash

I'm still new to bash and I've found similar questions to mine, but i still can't solve my problem. I have two files with 2 columns each, separated by a space.

file 1:

```
1 AGCATTTTTCAAACGAAAGATTTACTACCGATGTGT  
2 TGCTCACCAACAAAAACAGGCGTCTCAGCAGCAGCA  
3 GATCGAACCGGCTGCCTACTGCGTGTAAAGCCGCCC  
4 CCGACACAGAGAACATTAGAATACTCAGAGCCATNN   
5 TAAGCCTGAGCCTAAACCTAAGCCTAAACATAAGAA  
6 AGCAGAGAAGAGATGAGTTGTCGAGTGAGGCGTAAG  
7 AACGTTGAAAAATTATCCCGTCAACAGTCTCCAGAA  
8 GCCAGAGAGTAAAATATTGGGTGAAGCCAGAGAGTA  
9 TGCTCACCAACAAAAACAGGCGTCTCAGCAGCAGCA
```

file 2:

```
1 AGCATTTTTCAAACGAAAGATTTACTACCGATGTGT  
2 TGCTCACCAACAAAAACAGGCGTCTCAGCAGCAGCA  
3 NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN  
4 CCGACACAGAGAACATTAGAATACTCAGAGCCATNN  
5 TAAGCCTGAGCCTAAACCTAAGCCTAAACATAAGAA  
6 NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN  
7 NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN  
8 GCCAGAGAGTAAAATATTGGGTGAAGCCAGAGAGTA  
9 NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
```

I'd like to compare only the second columns of each file, line by line, and output a third file with only the non-matching lines.

output:

```
3 NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
6 NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
7 NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
9 NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next} !($2 in a)' file1 file2
3 NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
6 NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
7 NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
9 NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
```

**Explanation:**

```
NR == FNR {                  # While processing the first file
  a[$2]                      # just push the second field in an array
  next                       # move to next record of first file
}
!($2 in a)                   # print lines from file2 if array a doesn't that line
```

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -vf file1 file2
```

Output:

```
3 NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
6 NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
7 NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
9 NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
```

Comment: I think OP wants to compare only 2nd fields from both files but in this case this might work with the data provided,

Comment: Yes. This works because every line is unique and both files are sorted in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `diff` for this. `diff` will print out differences in two files.

```
/test>diff file1 file2
3c3
< 3 GATCGAACCGGCTGCCTACTGCGTGTAAAGCCGCCC
---
> 3 NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
6,7c6,7
< 6 AGCAGAGAAGAGATGAGTTGTCGAGTGAGGCGTAAG
< 7 AACGTTGAAAAATTATCCCGTCAACAGTCTCCAGAA
---
> 6 NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
> 7 NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
9c9
< 9 TGCTCACCAACAAAAACAGGCGTCTCAGCAGCAGCA
---
> 9 NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
```

Grepping for just differences from the second file:

```
/test>diff file1 file2 | grep ">"
> 3 NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
> 6 NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
> 7 NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
> 9 NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
```

Comment: If files are big this is best, maybe with `--suppress-common-lines`